# $dim(Im\varphi)$ where $p_\varphi(x)=x^6+ax^4+x^2$ for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Matrix of $\varphi$ is diagonizable in either basis.

$$p_\varphi(x)=x^6+ax^4+x^2$$

For any $a\in\mathbb{R}$. What is the dimension of $Im\varphi$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since we know that $\varphi$ is diagonizable, the kernel of $\varphi$ must have dimension $2$ as $x=0$ is no solution of $x^4+ax^2+1=0$.